# How to export my list of registered APIs and their specs in "Azure API Management" using the Java sdk?

Tags: java, azure, azure-api-management, azure-sdk

My code using the Azure Java SDK is as follows. I am able to authenticate and  get my API.Management generic resource but do not understand how to proceed to access all my registered APIs from the generic resource.

```
ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(
                clientID, domainID, secret, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
        Azure.Authenticated authenticated = Azure.authenticate(credentials);

        Azure azure = authenticated.withSubscription(subscriptionID);
        GenericResource genericResource = azure.genericResources().get(resourceGroupName,
                "Microsoft.ApiManagement", "service", resourceName);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to list APIs in Azure APi management with java, you can use the sdk `azure-mgmt-apimanagement`. For more details, please refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/apimanagement.

For example

1. Install SDK

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.apimanagement.v2019_01_01</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-mgmt-apimanagement</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-beta-1</version>
    </dependency>
```

2. Code

```
ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(
                clientID, domainID, secret, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
        ApiManagementManager apimanager=ApiManagementManager.configure().authenticate(creds,subscriptionId);
        Observable<ApiContract> result = apimanager.apis().listByServiceAsync("testapi06","testapi06");
        ArrayList<ApiContract> apis = new ArrayList<ApiContract>();
        result.doOnNext(r -> apis.add(r))
                .doOnCompleted(() -> System.out.println("compltested"))
                .subscribe();



        for (ApiContract api: apis) {



            System.out.println(api.name());



        }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Hury Shen , I am using version: '1.10.0-beta' but was able to figure it out using your example as a hint.